# What are the special symbols in Parquet files?

Tags: vim, parquet, non-printing-characters

I'm writing Parquet with Java API and syncing to HDFS.

When I get the Parquet file and read it with `vi`, I see many strange symbols like:

```
^U^B^U^@^U^H^U^H^\^X^H^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^X^H^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^V^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^U^@^U
```

I'm wondering how to interpret these.

Comment: Use `parquet-tools` to read parquet file. `parquet-tools cat file.parquet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [non-printable characters](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch25_07.htm).

Examples:

- `^@` is the representation of `NUL` character (ASCII value 0)
- `^M` is a carriage return

Comment: Thank you. I really get a new world. I use `od -c` to see the parquet, and get the correct data. Another question, why parquet use this format, I mean, why not use `0` instead of `^@`.

Comment: `0` is a value, `^@` is different, it is a `NUL` character, meaning "this character is empty".